# ListView seems blank with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview

Trying to set a simple `Listview` with an `ArrayAdapter` . however, can't see any list in output.

Here is the Code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Parse.initialize(this, "key", "key");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_board);


    countryLocal = new ArrayList<String>();


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Country");


    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> CountryList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(int i=0;i<CountryList.size();i++)
                {
                    temp = CountryList.get(i).getString("Name");

                    countryLocal.add(temp);
                    Log.d("OUT", "So the Val::------> " + countryLocal);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.user_list_item, countryLocal);

    ListView usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);


}
```

There seems no error in `Logcat`, but as I am loading data from Cloud, do I need to wait or load something from a different thread? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the query is being performed asynchronously, it's likely it's populating the `countryLocal` ArrayList after you've already created and set your adapter.

If the list is empty when `usersListView.setAdapter(...)` is called, then `adapter.getItemCount()` will return 0 and the ListView will not display anything.

It's your responsibility to let the ListView know when the data set has changed, so it can requery the adapter.

You can do this by using `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter - this lets anyone who is subscribed on the adapter know that the dataset has changed.

To allow you to do this, you can declare and create your ArrayAdapter before you start your query, which will allow you to have a reference with which to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when you know the query has completed.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Parse.initialize(this, "key", "key");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_board);

    countryLocal = new ArrayList<String>();
    final BaseAdapter namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.user_list_item, countryLocal);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Country");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> CountryList, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < CountryList.size(); i++) {
                temp = CountryList.get(i).getString("Name");
                countryLocal.add(temp);
                Log.d("OUT", "So the Val::------> " + countryLocal);
            }
            namesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });

    ListView usersListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! One more doubt, in case I am using RecyclerView, is the procedure the same ?

Comment: exactly the same - though it's a different class (RecyclerView.Adapter) I think the notifyDataSetChanged is still spelled the same. On RecyclerView, you even get more APIs that let you specify which item has changed, which the LayoutManager will use to animate only those items.

Comment: And , say If i want to go for a lazy loading with this one, what would be the best way?

Comment: What do you mean by lazy-loading in this context?

Comment: Lazy loading while using Cardview inside recyclerview, loading items, as scroll down, say if i have 10k elements, I want to display a set of 50 elements as the user scrolls in

Comment: Not sure what you mean but if it's what it sounds like, the ListView does this already. If you have 10k items in your adapter, it will not display 10k item views - it will only display enough to fill the screen, and as you scroll down, it'll reuse the item views that have scrolled off-screen.

Comment: If you mean pagination, so the adapter starts with 50 items, and then as they scroll to the bottom, another query is started so then the adapter knows about 50 + 50 new items, that's not something answerable in the comments section - I'd recommend a new question.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer and reply :)